# filter json data using josson

Tags: java, json

json library: [github.com/octomix/josson](https://github.com/octomix/josson)

My json data is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "pumpSeries": "CORACHROM 150",
      "selectionType": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
      ],
      "motorSeries": [
        "UMAI 150",
        "UMAG 150",
        "UMAH 150",
        "UMAI 150 CH"
      ]
    },
    {
      "pumpSeries": "BPH",
      "selectionType": [
        "A",
        "B"
      ],
      "motorSeries": [
        "HBC-Big",
        "NB-Small",
        "NB-Big",
        "HBCE"
      ]
    },
    {
      "pumpSeries": "BPH",
      "selectionType": [
        "C"
      ],
      "motorSeries": [
        "HBC-Big",
        "NB-Small"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "filter": "data[pumpSeries=pumpType & selectionType.contains(selectionType)].motorSeries",
  "pumpType": "BPH",
  "selectionType": "C"
}
```

My code to filter data

```
String json = "{\"data\":[{\"pumpSeries\":\"CORACHROM150\",\"selectionType\":[\"A\",\"B\",\"C\"],\"motorSeries\":[\"UMAI150\",\"UMAG150\",\"UMAH150\",\"UMAI150CH\"]},{\"pumpSeries\":\"BPH\",\"selectionType\":[\"A\",\"B\"],\"motorSeries\":[\"HBC-Big\",\"NB-Small\",\"NB-Big\",\"HBCE\"]},{\"pumpSeries\":\"BPH\",\"selectionType\":[\"C\"],\"motorSeries\":[\"HBC-Big\",\"NB-Small\"]}],\"filter\":\"data[pumpSeries=pumpType&selectionType.contains(selectionType)].motorSeries\",\"pumpType\":\"BPH\",\"selectionType\":\"C\"}";

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json);
System.out.println(josson.getNode("data[pumpSeries='BPH' & selectionType.contains('C')].motorSeries"));
```

**Output**

```
["HBC-Big","NB-Small"]
```

Now I want to filter the data using filter node used in json data instead of text. something like

```
System.out.println(josson.getNode("eval(filter)"));
```

here the text in filter node is

```
data[pumpSeries=pumpType & selectionType.contains(selectionType)].motorSeries
```

text should be resolved to below text and filter data

```
data[pumpSeries='BPH' & selectionType.contains('C')].motorSeries
```

Any help would be appreciated

Regards,
Pranav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data[pumpSeries='BPH' & selectionType.contains('C')].motorSeries
```

The filter `[]` is working on node `data`. `pumpType` and `selectionType` are under root node instead of `data`. You need to add a `$.` before the key in order to restart from the root.

So the filter query is:

```
data[pumpSeries=$.pumpType & selectionType.contains($.selectionType)].motorSeries
```